# How to Search for Files Recursively into Subdirectories

Tags: directory, ls

I am trying to look for all `XML` files in a particular directory and all sub-directories (recursively) inside it.

`ls -R *.xml` is only listing files in the current directory. I am quite sure, the sub-folders themselves have several `.xml` files, but none are showing up.

Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: You can do `ls -R | grep .xml`

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try using [Find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

```
sudo find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]xml'
```

Comment: is the sudo must, or it's there to ensure super user privileges?

Comment: I let you decide.  [Sudo](http://s1296.photobucket.com/user/joetjo/media/2013-06-13_2340_zpsecf4b1de.png.html), [No Sudo](http://s1296.photobucket.com/user/joetjo/media/2013-06-13_2340_001_zps4e3e080b.png.html).

Comment: Just out of interest. What is the advantage of `find` over `ls -R`?

Comment: @don.joey This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830036/difference-between-using-ls-and-find-to-loop-over-files-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @ShamimHafiz, sudo is useful if you need to search in a location where your current user does not have read right, I think this was the reason why sudo was included in command, just to be sure that you'll get all possible results

Comment: -1 for mixing `find` and `grep`, when `find` can do filtering using both regexes and globs, and not using `find`'s `-print0` and grep's `-z` when you do need to mix.

Comment: What is the print statement for, when removing it or not, the result is the same.

Comment: @Mitch the image hosting site you are using is blocked from where I am. Can you please share what the images were showing...? :)

Comment: @Christian Try [Sudo](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoVGYN7yjGEbgT6WYYWBXqp1szMm), [No Sudo](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoVGYN7yjGEbgT9e_xRSdCNMo0EN).

Answer (score 242):

You can do it with [find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/find.1.html) only:

```
find . -name '*.xml'
```

`.` is the current directory. If you need to search in another directory, replace `.` with the directory path.

Comment: Does it search for the required file recursively in the directory  rooted at current directory. In my case it just checked in the current directory only, didn't check the subdirectory.

Comment: @mostafiz, you need to quote the '*.xml' part. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually I searched for `.php` files in current directory. But it returned only `.php` files in current directory, didn't searched recursively in sub-directories. 

That's why I'm asking whether `find` command searches recursively or not.

Comment: @mostafiz, the `find` command searches recursively. If you don't quote the parameter, I think your shell might do an expansion on the `*`, so it will match the files in the current directory.

Comment: All right! May be I'd made some mistake. Now it is working perfectly!

Comment: you can use `-regex` or `-iregex` instead of `-name` if you want to use a regex.

Comment: Awesomesauce. Simple and effective!

Comment: thanks, needed that in Raspbian, combined with |shuf -n 1 at the end to pick one file randomly from the recursive list (to play a random .mp3 file from a folder hierarchy if some motion sensor was on)

Answer (score 24):

Try this command:

```
ls -R | grep '.*[.]xml'
```

`ls` doesn't have options to filter the output. For that you would need to use pipe. This passes the output from `ls` to `grep`, which then filters them to show just the `.xml` files.

Comment: Anyway to get this to show the directory it came from?

Comment: Mandatory link: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Answer (score 6):

#### bash

Using `globstar` shell option, we can make use of recursive globbing `./**/*`

```
bash-4.3$ shopt -s globstar
bash-4.3$ for i in  ./**/*.xml; do printf "%s\n" "$i" ; done
./adwaita-timed.xml
./bin/hw5/stuff/book/chapter42servletexample/build/web/META-INF/context.xml
./bin/hw5/stuff/book/chapter42servletexample/build/web/WEB-INF/beans.xml
./bin/hw5/stuff/book/chapter42servletexample/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

#### Perl

Perl has a module `Find`, which allows for recursive directory tree traversal. Within the special `find()` function, we can define a wanted subroutine and the directory that we want to traverse, in this example that's `.`. The one-liner in such case would be:

```
bash-4.3$ perl -le 'use File::Find; find(sub{-f && $_ =~ /.xml$/ && print $File::Find::name},".")' 
./adwaita-timed.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/jsf2demo/build/web/WEB-INF/beans.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/jsf2demo/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/liangweb/build.xml
```

#### Python

While Perl has a whole module dedicated to recursive tree traversal, Python has a neat function `walk()` that is part of `os` module, and repeatedly returns tuple of topmost path, list of all subdirectories, and list of filenames. We can do the following:

```
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import os,sys; [ sys.stdout.write(os.path.join(r,i)+"\n") for r,s,f in os.walk(".") for i in f if i.endswith(".xml") ]' 
./adwaita-timed.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/jsf2demo/build/web/WEB-INF/beans.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/jsf2demo/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
./CLEAR_DESKTOP/blahblah/hw5/stuff/book/liangweb/build.xml
```

This might be far neater as a script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,sys 
for r,s,f in os.walk("."): 
    for i in f: 
        if i.endswith(".xml") 
             print(os.path.join(r,i))
```

#### find

Other answers have mentioned `find` for recursive traversal, and that's the go-to tool for the job. What does need mention is the fact that `find` has multiple command line switches, such as `-printf` to print output in desired format, `-type f` to find only regular files, `-inum` to search by inode number, `-mtime` to search by modification date, `-exec <command> {} \;` to execute a particular command to process the file with passing file as argument ( where `{}` is standard `find` placeholder for current file) , and many others so please read the manpage for `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Gnome Filemanager you can click on the magnifying-glass icon (in the top-right usually) and then start typing to search in the current folder.

For some people (me) this is much easier that using the command-line.