# List all folders and subfolder with bash

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I tried to use PHP to read my folder and the subfolder to create a basic menu for me to use, but I noticed when I did that it took some time because it has to run it every time I go to the page.

Then I was thinking, why not use bash and make it create a text file that PHP can read and make it run every night with crontab? So I searched and tried but it was not so easy.

With this code I can get ONE subfolder

```
for D in /var/www/html/lib/*; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        echo "${D}"
    fi
done
```

it gave me

```
/var/www/html/lib/folder1
/var/www/html/lib/folder2
/var/www/html/lib/folder3
...
```

But the folders all have subfolders like

```
/var/html/lib/folder1/1990
...
```

My idea was to make a loop and then use

```
myfolder= "${D}"
addresstoremove="var/www/html/"

printf '%s\n' "${myfolder//$addresstoremove/}" >> textfile.txt
```

so it remove the address I do not need in my PHP code

Comment: Use `find`. More on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767402/5456794

Comment: Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/q/307876/295286

Comment: How is `/var/html/lib/folder1/1990` a subfolder of `/var/www/html/lib/folder1`? The path is definitely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find /var/www/html/lib/ -type d
```

or

```
find /var/www/html/lib/ -type d >> file.txt
```

Comment: Hmm nice easy code, like that alot but have the problem that it does not list in alphabetical order

Comment: @Cazz search on piping output to `sort` command.

Comment: find /var/www/html/lib/ -type d | sort >> file.txt